# Autocomplete with datalist

Tags: html

So I have a datalist which contains a list of all the people available like this:

```
<datalist id="available">
     <option value="1">Name</option>
     <option value="2">Ginger</option>
</datalist>
```

The issue is when I have the input setup like this:

```
<input name="persontobechosen" type="text" list="available" placeholder="Bob">
```

It autocompletes by value, I need value to be sent to the server but the user to start typing what's inbetween the tags.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `value` attribute to `"Name"` and `"Ginger"`?

Comment: That wouldn't do as I don't want "Name" and "Ginger" to be sent to the server I wan 1 and 2 to be sent to the server but for the user to type Name and Ginger

Comment: That can't be. The text displayed in a text `input` is its value, and its value is the data which will be submitted. Moreover, submitting "1" instead of "Name" would prevent you from knowing whether the user wrote "1" or "Name".

Comment: The issue is I need to have a frontend to the id which is shown. There is a for loop within php which outputs each option tag. I need the server to get the ID of the person, not the name.

Comment: Yes, this is weird. I usually want the opposite too. Can't have it. Browsers should display both value and label though, so you can turn it around so it technically matches.